# Inverting results when searching error logs in App Engine's dashboard?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to invert the results when searching error logs in the GAE dashboard? (similar to the grep -v command) For example, I want to be able to filter out paths that start with some string, X.

Answer (score 1):

To filter our requests that start with path /X you could try filtering on the path label:

```
path:/[^X].*
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, the logs search features in Google App Engine Dashboard are fairly limited.
One common suggestion is to [download the logs](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Logs) on your filesystem and parse them using your preferred *data crunching* tools.